# Monominoes in a grid up to row and column permutations

Tags: combinatorics

There are k monominoes in a grid, and some configurations are equivalent via permutations of lines and columns, as is exemplified in Fig. 1.

Let's call "multimino" such an equivalence class.

Figure 2 shows there are three multiminoes of order 2 - a vertical domino, an horizontal one and two random monominoes.

Here is the question - how many multiminoes of order k are ?

Using pencil and paper I found there are 1, 2, 3, 7, 12 multiminoes of order 1...5 that may be represented by 4-connected polyominoes; these would be components of 8-connected representatives.

While getting stuck, I started to learn Python but I am not sure this is the best thing to do. Someone whom already knows programming would write the code in ~ 15 minutes. Eventually I had the ideea to place here this issue.

PS : A monomino is an object that has the cycle index $x_1 \times y_1$ ; combinatorially speaking a monomino is the same thing with an arrow, for example.

[image: Hom many multiminoes of order k are ?]

Comment: Please define what you call a permutahedron. The definition I know of this term is for a very different concept.

Comment: Usual meaning [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Comment: oh my friend you so right, I just recalled, they were PermutoMINOES - thousands thanks, my bad, I corrected the issue.

Comment: The sequence is in OEIS: [A049311](https://oeis.org/A049311)

Comment: Also, the term [permutomino](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Permutomino) has already been established for a different concept.

Comment: Yes,  the number of (0,1) square matrices with n 1's and zero rows or columns ALLOWED :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full sequence is in OEIS [A049311](https://oeis.org/A049311)

6 of order 3:
[image]

16 of order 4:
[image]

34 of order 5:
[image]

Comment: I am affraid I not this one :( 
I have for order 4 another two : the S and the Z that are framed in a 3x3 bezel.

Comment: @Boyku The same are the third and fourth in the first column.

Comment: omg, 1+2+3+3+7 =16. Be blessed !

Comment: PS: re-checking my papers, I had the 1,2,3,7,12,32 of A056156.